# if string contains from list

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to check if any of the excluded sites show up. I can get it to work with just one site, but as soon as I make it a list, it errors at `if donts in thingy`:

> TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not tuple"

This is my code:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html, etree
import sys
import re

url = ("http://stackoverflow.com")

donts = ('stackoverflow.com', 'stackexchange.com')

r = requests.get(url, timeout=6, verify=True)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.select('a[href*="http"]'):

    thingy = (link.get('href'))

    thingy = str(thingy)

    if donts in thingy:

        pass

    else:

        print (thingy)
```

Comment: Because donts is a tuple and it needs a string.

Comment: I think you mean `if thingy in donts:` although `if thingy not in donts:` would be more direct than using a no-op then clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests 

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from lxml import html, etree

import sys

import re

url = ("http://stackoverflow.com")

donts = ('stackoverflow.com', 'stackexchange.com')

r = requests.get(url, timeout=6, verify=True)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.select('a[href*="http"]'):

    thingy = (link.get('href'))

    thingy = str(thingy)

    if thingy in donts :

        print (thingy)

    else:

        pass
```

Judge: string in tuple

Answer (score 0):

The crux of your problem is how you're searching your excluded list:

```
excluded = ("a", "b", "c")
links = ["a", "d", "e"]

for site in links:
    if site not in excluded:  # We want to know if the site is in the excluded list
        print(f"Site not excluded: {site}")
```

Reverse the order of your elements and this should work fine. I've inverted your logic here so you can skip the unnecessary `pass`.

As a side note, this is one reason clear variable names can help - they will help you reason about what the logic should be doing. Especially in Python where ergonomics like `in` exist, this is very useful.

Comment: this fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
import requests 

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from lxml import html, etree

import sys

import re

url = ("http://stackoverflow.com")

donts = ('stackoverflow.com', 'stackexchange.com')

r = requests.get(url, timeout=6, verify=True)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.select('a[href*="http"]'):

    thingy = (link.get('href'))

    thingy = str(thingy)

    if any(d in thingy for d in donts):

        pass

    else:

        print (thingy)
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because `str` is taken as an iteratable: ```>>> excluded = ("aa", "bb", "b")
>>> site = "bbb"
>>> any(d in site for d in excluded)
True```  Essentially, a site 'bbb' will be cause the if to be true even if the excluded site is 'bb'.